# Auto page load after wifi join

Tags: wifi, server, hotspot

I have a Pi configured to create an Access Point when not on home router,

Im trying to load a local webpage from my Pi when someone joins the open unsecured access point.

I want to be able to notify a message via the webpage thru simple html,

I know a webserver must be in place obviously, but I'm unsure what settings I need to make with what networking conf files to get the effect.

What steps should I take to achieve this?

Hotels use this for their AP verifications, and is right down the alley of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want a "captive portal".

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=84680) is a link to a forum thread that may be useful.